# Argument exception with JPA check the query syntax for correctness

Tags: jpa, db2, websphere

I am getting below exception using JPA+websphere+Db2.Does anyone have any idea.

org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Failed to execute query "select cpf from CardPaymentFunction cpf where cpf.cfmFunctionId= :aCfmFunctionId". Check the query syntax for correctness. See nested exception for details.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ic.a(ic.java:2290)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.bb.a(bb.java:3580)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.bb.a(bb.java:2007)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.bb.a(bb.java:1931)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.bb.p(bb.java:857)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.bb.k(bb.java:261)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.bb.d(bb.java:55)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.p.c(p.java:44)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.vb.j(vb.java:157)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.up.nb(up.java:2234)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.vp.a(vp.java:4637)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.vp.b(vp.java:4151)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.vp.mc(vp.java:771)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.j.mc(j.java:138)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.vp.executeQuery(vp.java:736)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.pmiExecuteQuery(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:1112)
```

Comment: why not start by looking at the OpenJPA LOG that tells you WHAT SQL is being invoked ...

Comment: The generated sql is perfectly fine.I have verified that

Comment: If it is "perfectly fine" then update your question and include it. And then others can offer ideas of why perfectly fine SQL causes the JDBC driver to blow its brains out

Comment: Edit your question to include the Db2 jdbc driver version that is being used by Websphere.  Also state the Db2-server version/platform/fixpack.  This symptom is associated with downlevel jdbc driver versions.

Comment: We are using 4.22.29 version of db2 jar